# XMLHttpRequest doesn't send request body in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I'm using XMLHttpRequest POST to call a SOAP service. The http request works fine in IE when I turn off cacheing. I can call a function and get the correct soap response xml back. However, when I run this in Firefox or Chrome, the http request object doesn't seem to have any body content. Here is my code:

```
   var xmlhttp = null;
   if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    alert("supports XMLHttpRequest");
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    // Internet Explorer
    try
    {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  }
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://www.zazzycard.com:22080/eBizCard/ws/eBizCardService", true);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
          alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
          alert(xmlhttp.responseXML);
         }
        }
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://ws.ebizcard.com/AuthenticateUser");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", 1000);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
        xmlhttp.send(xml);
```

Does anyone know why this is not working in Firefox? Thanks!

Comment: You havent defined xml variable any where in your code as you have used it in xmlhttp.send(xml)

Comment: Thanks guys. I figured out why firefox wasn't sending the POST data. Due to cross-site calling, firefox actually pre-flights my request by sending an OPTIONS request first to the server to ask for permission. My server doesn't handle this OPTIONS request and blows up. I had to remove the setRequestHeader() calls to avoid pre-flight requests. However, even though the service can now process the POST request correctly, the response I receive is empty/null. I'm very puzzled and frustrated at this point.

Comment: See this for reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control

Answer (score -5):

I know it's a cliche, but you really may want to use jQuery, to avoid all the `if (window.XMLHttpRequest) ...` stuff.

Comment: Thanks guys. I figured out why firefox wasn't sending the POST data. Due to cross-site calling, firefox actually pre-flights my request by sending an OPTIONS request first to the server to ask for permission. My server doesn't handle this OPTIONS request and blows up.

I had to remove the setRequestHeader() calls to avoid pre-flight requests. However, even though the service can now process the POST request correctly, the response I receive is empty/null. I'm very puzzled and frustrated at this point.

Comment: @Kang, you should post the modified code that you were able to get working as an answer and then mark it as accepted so that this question can better help others experiencing the same problem you had.